# Any need to manually remove an event listener that was manually added to an element in a React component?

Tags: reactjs

Consider the following scenario:

- I have a piece of (safe) HTML that I import in a js module and add to a React component using the [`dangerouslySetInnerHtml`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) prop.
- I then use the escape hatch that `ref`s provide to access the mounted React component.

  `let foo = this.refs.foo;`
- And add an event listener to a DOM element inside that mounted component

  `foo.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', callback, true);`

**Question** Will React remove this event listener automatically when the component is unmounted, or do I need to do this manually in `componentWillUnmount`? I can't imagine why React wouldn't remove it along with the DOM node it was added to, but I couldn't find any reference to support or contradict my intuition.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern browsers will collect event handlers of removed DOM elements.

But if you hold a reference of that DOM element somewhere, the event handlers can't be collected by a browser and cause memory leak.

So the safest way is to remove all the event handlers in your `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!